# JS function in <img>-tag doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, html

No matter where I put this, it won't work.
Meaning, it won't work inside the html file, in script-tags, not above the hideShow function not below it.
I have one JS file and a html file.
There are two functions in that JS file, the first one works fine, but when I try to call the second one, it just won't work, wheras when I try to execute the same piece of code directly inside the onclick="" property of the img it works.
Here is said JS file:

```
function hideShow(x,y) {
    var hide = document.getElementById(x);
    var show = document.getElementById(y);
    if (!hide.classList.contains("height-zero") && show.classList.contains("height-zero")) {
        hide.classList.add("height-zero");
        show.classList.remove("height-zero");
    } else {
        hide.classList.remove("height-zero");
        show.classList.add("height-zero");
    }
 }

function changeSource(x) {
    this.src = x;
}
```

And this is how I put it in the img-tag

```
<img src="img/label.png" onClick="changeSource('img/label2.png')">
```

Note I have more than one image

Comment: Because you're not passing the `this` as context. Function#call (thisCtx, args) or Function#apply (thisCtx, argCollectionObj) allows to do that -> `changeSource.call(this, "img/label2.png")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `this` to your function:

```
<img src="img/label.png" onClick="changeSource(this, 'img/label2.png')">

function changeSource(el, x) {
    el.src = x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought the function would know that 'this' refered to the object it was called from, but yeah, it works now. Will accept this as answer in 5 mins.

Comment: @J.H. It does not, because function can be called from other function, than `this` would link to two different things and that is wrong.

Comment: @mplungjan Can you provide source about that?

Comment: Just search "inline javascript practice" - it is quite established to separate view and controller. If you have inline handlers they may interfere with other scripts. For example I stopped using `<body onload`  in 1998 or so in favour of window.onload and later added event listeners if necessary.

Comment: @mplungjan But lots of event listeners will slow down your site. Having `onClick` provides less footprint...

Comment: Depends. One event handler for the document for any relevant link click or the added onclick to every relevant link? One place to change rather than many? I do not see slow sites just because they use jQuery delegation for example

Answer (score 1):

And an alternative of @Justinas answer is to pass `this` context to this function call, just like my comment said:

```
changeSource.call(this, "img/label2.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to other answer, if you move the event assignment from inline to the script tag, you can use `this` - right now your `this` is `window`.

If you have more than one image you can give them a class and do

```
window.onload=function() {
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".labelImage");
  for (var i=0, n=imgs.length;i<n;i++) {
    imgs[i].onclick=function() {
      this.src = this.getAttribute("data-src2"); 
      // or possibly this.src = this.src.replace(/label\./,"label2.")
    }
  }
}
```

using

```
<img class="labelImage" src="img/label1.png" data-src2="img/label1x.png" />
<img class="labelImage" src="img/label2.png" data-src2="img/label2x.png" />
<img class="labelImage" src="img/label3.png" data-src2="img/label2x.png" />
```

Inline, `this` also works, I however recommend you do not use inline functions:

```
<img src="img/label.png" onclick="this.src='img/label2.png'" />
```

Comment: Well, well, this solution is much more elegant. Thanks. EDIT: On a second thought, it doesn't work the way I want to use it though, I have a lot of images that I need to use that function on.

Comment: Your solution require unique ID for each image, so it's not re-usable and when you have 10 images, than you will be needing 10 `onClick` function declarations.

Comment: @J.H. The multiple images was not part of the original description. Please see the update for multiple images. If the clicked image has a post or prefix, then the data-src2 can be removed and the replace version used

Comment: @Justinas feel free to remove your downvote which was rather harsh given the lack of information from OP